# Prove that there exists a $p$-root for every member of $GF(q)$ and/or existence of power in $GF(q)$

Tags: finite-fields

I've been baffled by this question:
"Let $\mathrm{GF}(q)$, where $q$ is a prime power of $p$ ($q=p^h$), be a finite Galois field, prove that for each member of the field there exists a $p$ root of it."

I think I have a solution, but there's one thing I'm unsure about, if for every $b$ in $\mathrm{GF}(q) \rightarrow b^{(ap^-1)}$ is in $\mathrm{GF}(q)$ ($a$ is a random number) ?

Comment: Hint: $x^{q}=x$ in $\forall x\in\mathrm{GF}(q)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the answer I'm going to use the following theorems:

- every Galois-field contains a primitive element
- for all $x$, $x^q = x$
- every field is closed in relation to it's multiplication

Let $a$ be our primitive element, we define $b=a ^{p^h-1}$. Then 
$b^p = ( a^{p^h-1} ) ^p = a^q = a$.

Hence, since $a$ is our primitive element, for each $c$ in the field

$$c=a ^ l = (b^p) ^l = (b^l) ^ p$$

So every element has a $p$-root.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: Hi, click edit to see the latex José typed. Why do you need a primitive element ? It hides the map is $x \mapsto x^{p^{k-1}}$ (and not $x^{p^k-1}$). And that $x^{q-1}= 1$ for $x \in K^\times$ because it is a group with $q-1$ elements, so you don't need theorems.